# R: Issue when excluding column by name

Tags: r, dataframe, feature-selection

I am attempting to exclude a few columns from my dataset. I am trying:

```
df_enduse[,-c("EndUse_Solid_Cooking","EndUse_Solid_Lighting")]
```

which results in the error:

```
Error in -c("EndUse_Solid_Cooking", "EndUse_Solid_Lighting") : invalid argument to unary operator
```

On the other hand, the code below (for selection and not exclusion) does work:

```
df_enduse[,c("EndUse_Solid_Cooking","EndUse_Solid_Lighting")]
```

I am aware I can simply drop the columns from the dataset using

```
df_enduse <-  df_enduse[,!(names(df_enduse) %in% c("EndUse_Solid_Cooking","EndUse_Solid_Lighting"))]
```

However, I am curious why the previous attempt does not work.

Comment: You are trying to apply the unary operator minus '-' to a character string. That operator is not defined for that type. A similar syntax to the one you are proposing is supported in tidyverse, maybe that's what is confusing you?

Comment: Rather than names, if you use indexes it works.. I.e. `df_enduse[,-c(2,5)]`

Comment: also assigning as null works `df[, c("a, "b")] <- NULL`